# for of loop gives me undefined on some numbers and basic for loop works fine. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

Can someone explain to me this weird behavior? When I am using the for of loop it seems to be console logging the 2,5 but the rest are undefined. However, a normal for loop in the second block of code basically prints out all of the numbers. Much appreciated!

```js
function sort(arr){
    let items=arr.slice()
    console.log(items)
    for(let i of items){
        console.log(items[i])
        for(let j of items){
            if(items[j]<items[i]){
                // console.log(items[j])
                // console.log(items[i])
                let tmp = items[i]
                // console.log(tmp)
                items[j]=items[i]
                // console.log(items[j])
                items[i]=tmp
                // console.log(items[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}

let items = [4,1,5,3,2]
let sortItems = sort(items)


//VS//


function sort(arr){
    let items=arr.slice()
    console.log(items)
    for(let i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
        console.log(items[i])
        for(let j of items){
            if(items[j]<items[i]){
                // console.log(items[j])
                // console.log(items[i])
                let tmp = items[i]
                // console.log(tmp)
                items[j]=items[i]
                // console.log(items[j])
                items[i]=tmp
                // console.log(items[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}

let items = [4,1,5,3,2]
let sortItems = sort(items)
```

Comment: I'm surprised how that code didn't throw an exception. But, the main issue is, in the `for(let j of items)` code, the `j` constant actually holds the **value** of the item, not the **index** of the item. So the condition is probably failing.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul Because the values happen to be in range for a 5-item list... :)

Comment: explain a bit more?

Comment: The entire approach is flawed. `if(items[j]<items[i])` will sort in different directions during the same sort. It will sort ASC when `j > i` and it will sort DESC when `i < j`. You've basically written some weird shuffle function.

Answer (score 2):

`for..of` iterates over the *values* in the array, not its indices. You'd find your code to fail much earlier if you do e.g.

```
let items = [4093,1633,511,364,2642]
```

(e.g. where the values in the list aren't 0..4).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of